# Cross Contract e2e test type annotation needed for events

Tags: ink

I have two ink! contracts and one of those contracts is making calls to the other one using a `CallBuilder`.

I want to test that with `e2e` ink! tests and I am running into a problem.

For reference, one of the contracts is called `Identity` while the other one is called `AddressBook`.

The `AddressBook` contract is calling the `Identity` contract. The `e2e` test is in the `AddressBook` contract code.

The following `e2e` successfully compiles as far as there are no events in the `AddressBook` contract:

```rs
#[cfg(all(test, feature = "e2e-tests"))]
mod e2e_tests {
    use super::AddressBookRef;
    use ink_e2e::build_message;
    use identity::IdentityRef;

    type E2EResult<T> = std::result::Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>;

    #[ink_e2e::test]
    async fn add_identity_works(mut client: ink_e2e::Client<C, E>) -> E2EResult<()> {
        let identity_constructor = IdentityRef::new();

        let identity_acc_id = client
            .instantiate("identity", &ink_e2e::alice(), identity_constructor, 0, None)
            .await
            .expect("instantiate failed")
            .account_id;

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

When events are defined in the address book contract I get the following error:

```
error[E0284]: type annotations needed
   --> contracts/address-book/lib.rs:116:15
    |
116 |             self.env().emit_event(AddressBookCreated { owner: caller });
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: cannot satisfy `<_ as ContractEventBase>::Type == _`
help: try using a fully qualified path to specify the expected types
    |
116 |             <EnvAccess<'_, DefaultEnvironment> as EmitEvent<C>>::emit_event::<address_book::AddressBookCreated>(self.env(), AddressBookCreated { owner: caller });
    |             ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++          ~

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
   --> contracts/address-book/lib.rs:116:15
    |
116 |             self.env().emit_event(AddressBookCreated { owner: caller });
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^
    |
note: multiple `impl`s satisfying `EnvAccess<'_, DefaultEnvironment>: EmitEvent<_>` found
   --> contracts/address-book/lib.rs:33:1
    |
33  | #[ink::contract]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: and another `impl` found in the `identity` crate: `impl<'a> EmitEvent<identity::Identity> for EnvAccess<'a, <identity::Identity as ContractEnv>::Env>;`
    = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `ink::contract` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: try using a fully qualified path to specify the expected types
    |
116 |             <EnvAccess<'_, DefaultEnvironment> as EmitEvent<C>>::emit_event::<address_book::AddressBookCreated>(self.env(), AddressBookCreated { owner: caller });
    |             ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++          ~
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

See answer in [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9648/cross-contract-calls-and-events-dont-work-ink-4-2-1) post. It should help.

Use

```
<EnvAccess<'_, DefaultEnvironment> as EmitEvent<C>>::emit_event::<address_book::AddressBookCreated>(self.env(), AddressBookCreated { owner: caller });
```

instead of

```
self.env().emit_event(AddressBookCreated { owner: caller });
```